# Cosmos DB Not Respecting Json.Net CamelCaseNamingStrategy in Query

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net, azure-cosmosdb

I am creating a repository for Cosmos DB in .Net, and to be DRY and avoid decorating each class property with `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "thePropertyName")]`, I have decorated my classes with     `[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]`.

`CreateDocumentAsync` (for example) correctly serializes my Cosmos DB documents in JSON, using camel case names of the properties. So far so good.

My issue, however, is that when I query Cosmos DB via LINQ the SQL it generates to query COSMOS DB does not respect the `[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]` attribute decorating the class, and therefore no documents are returned. This is because Cosmos DB queries are case sensitive with respect to field/property names. For example, the following yield different results (note the case difference on Name):

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.name = "Health"
```

vs.

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Name = "Health"
```

I have confirmed this by checking the query SQL generated by `CreateDocumentQuery`, and have looked for options that may allow me to indicate casing of property names in `SqlQuerySpec` with no success.

So, my question is: Does anyone know how to have a LINQ query in Cosmos Db use the class defined camel casing strategy and not have to set each and every property manually via `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "thePropertyName")]`.

Thank you all in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Brian, Thanks for the formatting. My first question and completely forgot to format. Will try to avoid in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Currently not possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37490316/37421

I find setting it via property quite risky, and a bugfest.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I agree with your view that this has potential for bugs, and it's also tedious.  I'll wait patiently for the Cosmos DB team to address it as per their road map.