# Issue with mapping property name in POCO to field name in Cosmos Db In LINQ queries

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a model that defines field `date_sk` in Cosmos Db database, and correspondent `DateSk` in code:

```
    public class TestEntity { ...
       [JsonPropertyName("date_sk")]
       public Date DateSk { get; set; }
   }
```

I have no issue with running query like `SELECT * FROM c where c.date_sk='2011-11-11'` in Cosmos Db explorer, or as a raw query in c# like this:

```
   FeedIterator<TestEntity> feeder = GetContainer().GetItemQueryIterator<TestEntity>(
                    new QueryDefinition($"SELECT * FROM c where c.date_sk='2011-11-11'"));
```

However when I try to run LINQ alternative:

```
var feeder = GetContainer()
                .GetItemLinqQueryable<TestEntity>()
                .Where(f => f.DateSk == "2021-11-11");
```

it throws no error, but nothing returned back, and when I put a breakpoint to see SQL query that runs behind scene, I can see `SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE (root["DateSk"] = "2021-11-11")`. It shows `DateSk` property name used f;at straight instead of `date_sk` real field name set with JsonPropertyName attribute. Interestingly the mapping works fine if I use other than LINQ queries, at least data is properly transferred one direction date_sk->DateSk, so the JsonPropertyName attribute works fine in the rest of situations

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to use Linq here, though?

Comment: I found some posts from 2016 of people complaining of the same thing: that CosmosDB's Linq provider does not respect JSON property names (either `Newtonsoft.Json` or `System.Text.Json`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489768/how-to-tell-documentdb-sdk-to-use-camelcase-during-linq-query/37490316#37490316 - sucks

Comment: Also https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/317

Comment: it's simplified example, using LINQ is preferable for maintainability reason (less hardcode, strongly typed). Thank you links you provided, they are all about Newtonsoft Json serializer, I've been using different, namespace System.Text.Json, one that Microsoft moving toword

Comment: btw I'm setting serializer setting to camel case (PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase) like these links recommend, it does not help

Comment: I believe Newtonsoft is used internally by the SDK. If you're using `JsonPropertyName` from System.Text.Json, that won't be respected by SDK. This among other reasons is why I became happier after I persuadd myself to get away from LINQ and use `QueryDefinition` instead. Entire classes of confusion, avoided.

Comment: Well, seems like Microsoft simply does not support LINQ conversion in its  System.Text.Json  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f6d33682-a02a-4d9e-b3af-470fa3f7836c/linq-not-recognizing-jsonpropertyname-when-using-systemtextjson?forum=csharpgeneral, Newtsonsoft.Json works though